# Number rows of table in decimal and hexadecimal with multiple counters

Tags: tables, macros, counters, xparse

---

**TL;DR** My code to automatically number a table with two running counters in decimal and zero-padded hexadecimal (using the `fmtcount` and `array` packages) is not working.

---

I'm trying to automatically number a table with multiple running counters in decimal and hexadecimal, where the hexadecimal numbers are zero-padded so that they have two digits. It should look something like this:

| Counter A, Hex | Counter A, Dec | Counter B, Hex | Counter B, Dec | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 0 | 00 | 0 | First row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 01 | 1 | Second row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 02 | 2 | Third row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 03 | 3 | Fourth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 04 | 4 | Fifth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 05 | 5 | Sixth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 06 | 6 | Seventh row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 07 | 7 | Eighth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 08 | 8 | Ninth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 09 | 9 | Tenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0A | 10 | Eleventh row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0B | 11 | Twelfth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0C | 12 | Thirteenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0D | 13 | Fourteenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0E | 14 | Fifteenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 0F | 15 | Sixteenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 10 | 16 | Seventeenth row of the table |
| 00 | 0 | 11 | 17 | Eighteenth row of the table |
| 01 | 1 | 00 | 0 | Nineteenth row of the table |
| 01 | 1 | 01 | 1 | Twentieth row of the table |
| 01 | 1 | 02 | 2 | Twenty-first row of the table |

In order to accomplish this, I've defined several macros (the third counter, `autoCounterC`, is in case I need a third running counter in a different table) and written my document like this:

So, my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape,letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse,fmtcount,array,longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{autoCounterA}
\newcounter{autoCounterB}[autoCounterA]
\newcounter{autoCounterC}[autoCounterB]

\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{}

\providecommand{\resetAutoCounters}{\setcounter{autoCounterA}{0} \setcounter{autoCounterB}{0} \setcounter{autoCounterC}{0}}

\providecommand{\enableAutoCounterCommands}{
    % \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterA}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{\theautoCounterA}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterA}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{\stepcounter{autoCounterA}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterB}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterB}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{\stepcounter{autoCounterB}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterC}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterC}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{\stepcounter{autoCounterC}}
}
\providecommand{\disableAutoCounterCommands}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{}
}

\begin{document}
\resetAutoCounters \disableAutoCounterCommands
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white}
\begin{longtable}{c<{\autoCounterAHex[2]}|c<{\autoCounterADec}|c<{\autoCounterBHex[2]}|c<{\autoCounterBDec}|p{120pt}<{\stepAutoCounterB}}
    \textbf{Counter A, Hex} & \textbf{Counter A, Dec} & \textbf{Counter B, Hex} & \textbf{Counter B, Dec} & Description \\ \hline \enableAutoCounterCommands \endhead
    &&&& First row of the table \\
    &&&& Second row of the table \\
    &&&& Third row of the table \\
    &&&& Fourth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fifth row of the table \\
    &&&& Sixth row of the table \\
    &&&& Seventh row of the table \\
    &&&& Eighth row of the table \\
    &&&& Ninth row of the table \\
    &&&& Tenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Eleventh row of the table \\
    &&&& Twelfth row of the table \\
    &&&& Thirteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fourteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fifteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Sixteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Seventeenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Eighteenth row of the table \\ \stepAutoCounterA
    &&&& Nineteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Twentieth row of the table \\
    &&&& Twenty-first row of the table \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The document compiles with `xelatex` without any errors, but it appears that the counters are not working at all. Furthermore, there is an extra row in the table that contains only the `0` character in the first column (there are no divider lines between the remaining columns):
[image: The counters in the output do not appear at all, and there is an extra row in the table that contains only the 0 character in the first column (there are no divider lines between the remaining columns).]

**How can I correct my existing code to produce the table shown in the correct sample output above, and what is wrong with my current version?**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is connected to commands in your approach needing to be defined with global scope.

In this proof of concept I simply moved `\enableAutoCounterCommands` to before the longtable so I did not have to learn the new LaTeX syntax and where to put the `\global`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape,letterpaper]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse,fmtcount,array,longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcounter{autoCounterA}
\newcounter{autoCounterB}[autoCounterA]
\newcounter{autoCounterC}[autoCounterB]

\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{}
\newcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{}

\providecommand{\resetAutoCounters}{%
   \setcounter{autoCounterA}{0}%
   \setcounter{autoCounterB}{0}%
   \setcounter{autoCounterC}{0}%
}

\providecommand{\enableAutoCounterCommands}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterA}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterA}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{\stepcounter{autoCounterA}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterB}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterB}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{\stepcounter{autoCounterB}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\hexadecimal{autoCounterC}}}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{\padzeroes[##1]{\decimal{autoCounterC}}}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{\stepcounter{autoCounterC}}
}
\providecommand{\disableAutoCounterCommands}{
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterAHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterADec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterA}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterBDec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterB}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCHex}{O{1}}{}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\autoCounterCDec}{O{1}}{}
    \renewcommand{\stepAutoCounterC}{}
}

\begin{document}
\resetAutoCounters \disableAutoCounterCommands
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white}
\enableAutoCounterCommands 
\begin{longtable}{c<{\autoCounterAHex[2]}|c<{\autoCounterADec}|c<{\autoCounterBHex[2]}|c<{\autoCounterBDec}|p{120pt}<{\stepAutoCounterB}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Counter A, Hex}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Counter A, Dec}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Counter B, Hex}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Counter B, Dec}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{p{120pt}}{Description }\\ \hline
\endhead
    &&&& First row of the table \\
    &&&& Second row of the table \\
    &&&& Third row of the table \\
    &&&& Fourth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fifth row of the table \\
    &&&& Sixth row of the table \\
    &&&& Seventh row of the table \\
    &&&& Eighth row of the table \\
    &&&& Ninth row of the table \\
    &&&& Tenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Eleventh row of the table \\
    &&&& Twelfth row of the table \\
    &&&& Thirteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fourteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Fifteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Sixteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Seventeenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Eighteenth row of the table \\ \stepAutoCounterA
    &&&& Nineteenth row of the table \\
    &&&& Twentieth row of the table \\
    &&&& Twenty-first row of the table \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]